# Xcode app delegate to each view controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates

I have been working on an Xcode tutorial and cannot get around this problem.The tutorial is [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/06/30/iphone-development-tutorial-add-core-data-to-a-tab-bar-application-and-save-user-data/#comment-14942)

The error I am getting is:

> +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Contact''

at this line (I have changed destination to contact):

```
Contact *contact = (Contact *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

I am pretty sure the problem is because I have not completed point number 11 as I am unsure how to do it using Xcode 4.3.2 and storyboards. Does anyone know?

Comment: That error has to do with steps 4 & 5 in your tutorial. Make sure you spelled the entity name correctly, it's also case sensitive. This error has nothing to do with storyboards.

Comment: Add "Contact" in coremodel, after delete the app in your device and run. Maybe this is the problem

Comment: Hmm, the entity is definitely spelt correctly. And I have worked through the tutorial again, there are no problems in the code. @SimonePistecchia how do you go about adding "Contact" to core model?

Comment: cxdatamodel. If you make a change, delete and reinstal the app.

Comment: well i downloaded the code of the tutorial that you have mentioned and its working fine.. Not showing any error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the context to the next viewcontroller just like in Stephens answer. However, you must also remember to add the context property to you new viewcontrollers by adding

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
```

to your header file and

```
@synthesize context;
```

to your implementation file.

You can do the following to check if you get the context:

In your viewdidload:

```
if (context == nil) 
{ 
    context = [(YOURAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
}
```

If this doesn't help. Try resetting your simulator as it seems to bug a lot when you are messing around with Coredata.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have done these guides if I log context i get "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6f46a30>" (or number variant), but still it crashes when I call the save function: NSInternalInconsistencyException for the same reason above.

Comment: @Patrick Correct me if Im wrong but didnt I post you the correct answer 5 hours before you did and with just a different name for the context?

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad! There must have been two problems as this didn't immediately fix it! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the entitiy exists, it seems more likely that you're missing the following like from point number ten:

```
enterDataViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Either that or your managedObjectContext is not set up correctly in the app delegate.